# Resolution of the Eye-Light Rays and Diffraction

Tags: optics, visible-light, vision

Please look at the problem.
The problem is solved for me. 
[image]

However, I don't understand why the angle alpha is considered to stay constant when the rays go through the lens. The ray along the distance $s$ does **not** get refracted, which I agree with. But the ray along the top point of the circle **does** get refracted once it gets to the liquid inside the eye. Can someone clarify why the textbook does not take that into account?

Comment: What I meant was the following: when the ray that is not parallel to the optical axis (the one going from the top point of the circle to through the middle of the lens), that ray should deviate because the refractive index of the eye is 1.33.

Comment: I don't understand why there would not be refraction there.

Answer (score 1):

The diagram is simplified, because refraction actually occurs at the front surface of the cornea and at both surfaces of the lens.  (Also the eyeball is not a sphere.)  *However*, taking the cornea and lens as a single compound lens, that lens does have an "optical centre", such that rays passing through that point are not deviated.  The author has chosen to draw those rays that pass through the optical centre - this is how the size of the image is calculated.

Calculating the position of the optical centre for a compound lens is not trivial.  The author has assumed it lies somewhere near the centre of the anatomical lens.

For a more accurate treatment, you might look [here](http://www.eyecalcs.com/DWAN/pages/v1/v1c033.html), especially at "nodal points".

Comment: I understand the diagram is simplified. What I am asking is: for a ray that just got out of the lens and that is going through the liquid of the eye, will there be refraction there?
In case of refraction: then alpha will not be equal on both sides of the lens... @akrasia

Comment: @yolo123 No, there won't be. That's the whole point. The lens is known to have an optical centre which is defined by precisely that property; the author then assumes it's somewhere close to the anatomical centre.

Answer (score 0):

I believe both rays drawn in that diagram go thru the center of the lens aperture, so they in fact are not refracted.   That is, both the top and the bottom of the circular object are at equal radiuses (distances) from the optic axis.

Your confusion may be with the rays drawn from a single object point when finding the size of the focussed image, in which case one ray goes thru the center and one (parallel to the optic axis until it hits the lens) is indeed refracted.  But what this diagram shows is the separation of the two image points, not the focussed image height per se.

Comment: What I am asking is: for a ray that just got out of the lens and that is going through the liquid of the eye, will there be refraction there? In case of refraction: then alpha will not be equal on both sides of the lens... @Carl Witthoft